# Logstash Aggregate map working only for few rows while merging two data sources

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am using the latest version of logstash(7.6.2). I am trying to **merge rows from two different files** using a common ID. Find below the samples of the two data sources. Also, find below my desired output.

**Sample Data 1** with columns **ID, Country, State**

```
111 US NY
112 IN KA
113 US MA
```

**Sample Data 2** with columns **ID and Info**

```
111 abc
111 abd
112 xyz
112 xya
113 qwe
113 qwr
```

**Desired Output with merge**

```
111 abc US NY
111 abd US NY
112 xyz IN KA
112 xya IN KA
113 qwe US MA
113 qwr US MA
```

I have tried using aggregate as shown in the below config file. I have also set pipeline workers to 1 and disabled java execution by adding the following commands in logstash.yml

```
pipeline.workers: 1
pipeline.java_execution: false
```

**Config File**

```
input { 
file{
    path => ["C:/Users/Nani/Sample_Data/Mapping.txt"]
    path => ["C:/Users/Nani/Sample_Data/sample.log"]
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "NUL"
}
}
filter{
grok {
        match => ["message","%{INT:ID},%{WORD:COUNTRY},%{GREEDYDATA:CITY},%{GREEDYDATA:STATE},%{GREEDYDATA:Location}\r"]
        match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\s\s%{LOGLEVEL:LOGLEVEL1}\s%{WORD:Info}:%{INT:ID}\s\-\s%{GREEDYDATA:LOGLEVEL2}\r"]
        remove_field => ["message"]
    }
    if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {drop{}}
    mutate{
        convert => { "ID" => "string" }
    }
    if [Country] =~ /.+/ {
        aggregate {
            task_id => "%{ID}"
            code => "
            map['country'] = event.get('Country')
            map['state'] = event.get('State')
            event.cancel()
            "
        }
        drop{}
    } 
    if ![Country] {
        aggregate {
            task_id => "%{ID}"
            code => "
            event.set('Country', map['country'])
            event.set('State', map['state'])
            event.cancel()
            "
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to obtain the merge results for the sample but when i try it on entire data only few rows get updated with the merged columns instead of all the rows.

I am I missing anything here? Any help here is appreciated. TIA

Comment: Why do you have a `drop { }` filter after an aggregate in your first conditional? It will drop everything that enter this conditional. Also, it would help if you share your full config.

Comment: ```Drop{}``` is just to remove **Sample Data 1** after storing the maps. This will make sure that I won't have redundant data as I copy these columns to **Sample Data 2**. I have added my full config file above. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

In case if anyone is looking for this. I found a workaround!
Used **Elasticsearch Filter Plugin** as below to merge the two indexes.
Config File

```
elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
        index => "mapping_file"
        query => "ID:%{[ID]}"
        fields => {"COUNTRY" => "COUNTRY"}
}
```

Pushed the **data 1** into ElasticSearch as **mapping_file** and used it in the **ElasticSearch Filter plugin** while pushing **data 2**

Hope it helps!